# Ubuntu Encryption - Protect data in the case of Physical Server Access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption

Looking to Encrypt a system, such that if someone has physical access to the server they can not clone the hard drive or copy data off of it.    I require the services to be running such that the system can do its job, but i want to protect the servers data.  The server needs to be able to be restarted by anyone in the event of a power outage without the need for a password to be entered.

I will prevent access to the USB ports and Bios.

Does anyone have an idea of how i can do this, any suggestions would be welcome, and thinking outside the box is acceptable.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That does not seem possible in general without the use of dedicated hardware.

If an attacker can clone the hard drive and boot the image under virtualization, when the system boots, it can never be 100% sure if it is running on the real hardware or not.

If your server has a hardware TPM, you can use a modified bootloader like TrustedGRUB or tboot so that the encryption keys for the drive are stored in the TPM, and will only be disclosed if it can check that the OS has not been tampered with. The TPM itself is not supposed to be cloneable.

If you only want to defend against someone stealing the HD, cloning it and putting it back in place, storing the key in the TPM and reading it at boot may be sufficient, and in this case you don't need a trusted bootloader, just a userland TPM software stack like TrouSerS.

This is however insecure if the attacker takes the HD, clones it,  modifies the boot sequence to leak the keys somewhere, and puts back the modified HD. To defend against this new attack, you really need to run a trusted bootloader.

If you choose such a solution, do not forget to backup the keys to some secure offline storage. Otherwise it will be difficult to recover your drives if the motherboard or TPM fails.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I think TPM may be the way to go.  I see that Ubuntu has something called Trousers which uses the TPM 2.0 is this similar to TrustedGRUB?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/414747/does-ubuntu-use-tpm-2-0-chip

Comment: Trousers is an userspace component to use the TPM, yes. It may be sufficient, see my edit for details